# Why does my websse return null?

Tags: php, html

This is my code:

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');<br/>
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo  "data: now time is ".$time;

flush();
```

HTML:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>websse</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='pp'></p>

        <script>

            if(typeof(EventSource)!== 'undefined'){
                es = new EventSource('websse.php');
                es.onmessage=function(event)
                {
                    document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
                    console.log(event.data);
                };

            }else{
                p.innerHTML = "--------";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, what is your question, and what have you tried so far? Please try to elaborate.

Comment: i want the php code return time ,but it doesn't work. php code can echo time successful ,but the page can't receive the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 2 newline characters after any data is output in your *websse.php* script, so:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "data: now time is " . $time . "\n\n"; // <-- here
```

Comment: it works. but i don't understand . Is this a prescribed format?

Comment: Yup : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ - scroll down to **Event Stream Format**